# Throw custom exception when item not found in a Kotlin collection

Tags: kotlin, collections

I want to find a person from a list, or throw a PersonNotFoundException otherwise.

The `first()` function from `kotlin.collections` throws `NoSuchElementException` in this scenario, but I want to throw my custom exception i.e. PersonNotFoundException.

Currently I'm using the following logic:

```
val persons: List<Person> = listOf(...)
val name: String = "Bob"

persons.firstOrNull {
    it.name == name
}.let {
  it ?: throw PersonNotFoundException("No person was found with name $name")
}
```

But I'm not quite satisfied with it.
It feels that there is some existing function for this use case that I'm not aware of.

Can anyone help me improve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even need `let`. All `let` does is it lets you refer to the found thing using `it`.

The code can be shortened to the more idiomatic:

```
persons.firstOrNull {
    it.name == name
} ?: throw PersonNotFoundException("No person was found with name $name")
```